# Macro to attach SAVED version of document to an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, macros

I have a macro attached to a command button that preps an email for the user to send. The problem is, the user will have to remember to save the document before pressing the send button. I'd rather not rely on the users to remember to save, it leaves too much room for error. Is there a macro I can input before the SendEmail macro that will automatically save the document? This is what I have so far:

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "me"
    .Subject = "Completed Testing Schedule " & Date
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, before you send the email, you can do:

`Documents.Save NoPrompt:=True, OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat`

or

`If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then ActiveDocument.Save`

You may want to add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before that, so you don't see that notice "Do you want to save", then put `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after, to turn notifications back on.

Edit: It's not clear if you're running this from Excel, which I assume you are.

Comment: I am running this from Excel and your solution worked! Thanks.